# What does the r function requirenamespace() mean?

Tags: r

Every package installation instruction starts with:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
```

I was wondering what the `requireNamespace()` function means?

The definition given in the documentation doesn't make much sense to me. How is `requireNamespace()` different to `loadNamespace`?

> a wrapper for loadNamespace analogous to require that returns a logical value"

And are the following two lines always necessary to precede each new package installation?

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It can be used to _test_ if a package is installed and loadable because it comes back with either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Which leads to the standard use you see and have quoted here of installing-if-needed (_i.e._ when `FALSE` was returned).

Comment: Thank you. I see, so requireNamespace checks and loads a namespace, and therefore in the case above, it is to check if BiocManager is already loaded, otherwise, it'll install BiocManager. Does that mean that after the first installation containing these two lines, we could skip these two lines for all subsequent installations because BiocManager would already be installed?

Comment: More like "... for all subsequent _uses_ ..."  on this machine.